# Add Custom Language File To Geshi

Tags: 8

Drupal 8.4.x

I have a custom language file I'd like to add to Geshi.

I've gone through the Geshi docs and can't seem to find anything on adding custom languages. But maybe I am just missing that section...

I'd like to figure out the proper way to get custom language files into Geshi. Has anyone accomplished this?

I am using composer, and am wondering if I should look at the proper way to include custom files via composer, or should this be a task completed with a custom module?